# Prove that for a direct product group $G=E\otimes F$, $E$ and $F$ are normal (invariant) subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I am learning Group theory from a book about Group theory for physicists and I want to prove something that is probably really elementary:

for a direct product group $G=E\otimes F$, $E$ and $F$ are invariant/normal subgroups.

I use the following (possibly sloppy) notation:
Elements in $G$ can be expressed as $g_{ij}=(e_i, f_j)$ with $e_i\in E$, $i=1,..,\dim(E)$ and $f_j\in F$, $j=1,..,\dim(F)$ such that $(e_i,f_j)(e_{i'}.f_{j'})=(e_ie_{i'},f_jf_{j'})$.

My attempt to show the above is the following:
To show that $E$ is a normal subgroup, I have to show that $g_{ij}^{-1}Eg_{ij}=E,\ \forall g_{ij}\in G$. So, I want to show that $$(e_i,f_j)^{-1}(e_k,1)(e_i,f_j)$$ gives one and only one element in $E$, with $(e_k,1)$ belonging in $E$ (I am aware of the abuse of notation here--sorry for this) and $\forall  i=1,..,\dim E,\ j=1,..,\dim F$.

Carrying out the product, we get $$(e_i^{-1}e_je_i,1)$$
Now I know that this belongs to $E$ (because the product of elements in a group belongs in the group) but I think that I have to show that this gives us exactly one element in $E$. How can I show this?

**EDIT:** I think I got it. Since $(e_i^{-1}e_je_i,1)\in E$, we can write it as $(e_i^{-1}e_je_i,1)=(e_k,1)$ for some $k$. Since $E$ is a group $(e_k,1)=(e_{k'},1)$ only if $k=k'$. So $(e_i^{-1}e_je_i,1)$ gives exactly one element in $E$.

Comment: You can post your answer as an answer.

Comment: @Berci I didn't know this! I'll do this tomorrow as it's really late in my country now! Cheers! Happy I got it right and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\dim E$ notation is not lucky. You may want to use the cardinalities $|E|$ and $|F|$, but be aware that the claim holds for infinite groups as well.

Since multiplication on $E\times F$ is well defined (and associative), of course there is a unique value of $(e_i, f_j)^{-1}(e_k, 1)(e_i,f_j)$, and as you correctly calculated, is indeed in $E\times \{1\}$.